# Parsing Filter Needed For Newline Delimited JSON format

Tags: json, parsing, google-bigquery, jq

I'm running into a problem as I attempt to automate an API process into BigQuery.

The issue is that I need the data to be in a newline delimited JSON format to go into my BigQuery database but the data I'm pulling does not do that, so I need to parse it out.

[Here is a link to pastebin so you can get an idea of what the data looks like](http://pastebin.com/d64nDAdz), but also, here it is just because:

```
{"type":"user.list","users":[{"type":"user","id":"581c13632f25960e6e3dc89a","user_id":"ieo2e6dtsqhiyhtr","anonymous":false,"email":"test@gmail.com","name":"Joe Martinez","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"b5vkxvop","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":{"type":"location_data","city_name":"Houston","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":29.7633,"longitude":-95.3633,"postal_code":"77002","region_name":"Texas","timezone":"America/Chicago","country_code":"USA"},"last_request_at":1478235114,"last_seen_ip":"66.87.120.30","created_at":1478234979,"remote_created_at":1478234944,"signed_up_at":1478234944,"updated_at":1478235145,"session_count":1,"social_profiles":{"type":"social_profile.list","social_profiles":[]},"unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920P Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.68 Mobile Safari/537.36","tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[]},"segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea275bfcebabd516d963"},{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea265bfcebabd516d962"}]},"custom_attributes":{"claimCount":"1","memberType":"claimant"}},{"type":"user","id":"581c22a19a1dc02c460541df","user_id":"1o3helrdv58cxm7jf","anonymous":false,"email":"test@mail.com","name":"Joe Coleman","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"b5vkxvop","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":{"type":"location_data","city_name":"San Jose","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":37.3394,"longitude":-121.895,"postal_code":"95141","region_name":"California","timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","country_code":"USA"},"last_request_at":1478239113,"last_seen_ip":"216.151.183.47","created_at":1478238881,"remote_created_at":1478238744,"signed_up_at":1478238744,"updated_at":1478239113,"session_count":1,"social_profiles":{"type":"social_profile.list","social_profiles":[]},"unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0","tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[]},"segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea275bfcebabd516d963"},{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea265bfcebabd516d962"}]},"custom_attributes":{"claimCount":"2","memberType":"claimant"}}],"scroll_param":"24ba0fac-b8f9-46b2-944a-9bb523dcd1b1"}
```

The two problems are the first line:

```
{"type":"user.list","users":
```

And the final piece at the bottom:

```
,"scroll_param":"24bd0rac-b2f9-46b2-944a-9zz543dcd1b1"}
```

If you eliminate those two, you are simply left with the necessary data needed, and I know what filter is needed to parse it out to put it in newline delimited format.

[You can see for yourself by playing around with this tool](https://jqplay.org/#), but if you only copy and paste everything from that first open bracket to the close bracket on the final line, set it to "Compact Output" and apply the filter:

```
.[]
```

The result will be like what you see here, [in a nice and neat newline delimited format like you see here.](http://pastebin.com/Dy27itgD), also here it is not in the link:

```
{"type":"user","id":"581c13632f25960e6e3dc89a","user_id":"ieo2e6dtsqhiyhtr","anonymous":false,"email":"test@gmail.com","name":"Joe Martinez","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"b5vkxvop","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":{"type":"location_data","city_name":"Houston","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":29.7633,"longitude":-95.3633,"postal_code":"77002","region_name":"Texas","timezone":"America/Chicago","country_code":"USA"},"last_request_at":1478235114,"last_seen_ip":"66.87.120.30","created_at":1478234979,"remote_created_at":1478234944,"signed_up_at":1478234944,"updated_at":1478235145,"session_count":1,"social_profiles":{"type":"social_profile.list","social_profiles":[]},"unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920P Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.68 Mobile Safari/537.36","tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[]},"segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea275bfcebabd516d963"},{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea265bfcebabd516d962"}]},"custom_attributes":{"claimCount":"1","memberType":"claimant"}}
{"type":"user","id":"581c22a19a1dc02c460541df","user_id":"1o3helrdv58cxm7jf","anonymous":false,"email":"test@mail.com","name":"Joe Coleman","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"b5vkxvop","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":{"type":"location_data","city_name":"San Jose","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":37.3394,"longitude":-121.895,"postal_code":"95141","region_name":"California","timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","country_code":"USA"},"last_request_at":1478239113,"last_seen_ip":"216.151.183.47","created_at":1478238881,"remote_created_at":1478238744,"signed_up_at":1478238744,"updated_at":1478239113,"session_count":1,"social_profiles":{"type":"social_profile.list","social_profiles":[]},"unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0","tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[]},"segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea275bfcebabd516d963"},{"type":"segment","id":"57d2ea265bfcebabd516d962"}]},"custom_attributes":{"claimCount":"2","memberType":"claimant"}}
```

So what I need is a filter I can apply in the same manner I used .[] that pull out all the text prior to the first open bracket (as I highlighted above) as well as all the text prior to the closed bracket at the end.

But here's where the final problem comes in. While I need that final piece of text out of the equation, I still do need that string of letters and numbers known as the scroll paramater. This is because in order to fully capture all the data I need in the API, I need to continuously use the new scroll paramater it generates from the command line call until all the data is in.

The initial call looks as such:

```
$ curl -s https://api.program.io/users/scroll -u 'dG9rOmU5NGFjYTkwXzliNDFfNGIyMF9iYzA0XzU0NDg3MjE5ZWJkZDoxOjA=': -H 'Accept:application/json'
```

But in ordere to get all the info in, I need that scroll parameter for a seperate call that looks like:

```
curl -s https://api.intercom.io/users/scroll?scroll_param=foo -u 'dG9rOmU5NGFjYTkwXzliNDFfNGIyMF9iYzA0XzU0NDg3MjE5ZWJkZDoxOjA=': -H 'Accept:application/json' >scroll.json
```

So while I need to get rid of the text in the blob that contains the paramater in order to put it in newline delimited format, I still need to extract whatever that paramater is to loop back into another script that will continue to run until it is empty.

Would love to hear any advice in working around this!

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: Really? Does it really make a difference? Y'all really about to make me go and format everything when its conveniently sitting right there in an easy to digest format?

Comment: And when that site goes down? What will future readers of this question do? Use their imagination as to what the data should be?

Comment: Alright, well, I added it to my question, just in case of the event in which Pastebin, a siet that has been around for 15 years, goes down

Comment: I'm working 15 years and I've never heard about new-line-delimited-json. What's the problem with parsing the JSON and getting data you need?

Comment: http://specs.okfnlabs.org/ndjson/ 

But the problem is how do I parse out those two problem lines of texts?

Comment: Ctrl-K is hard to press, I understand.

Comment: Ohhhh that's all I have do? Haha my b, homey

Answer (score 0):

Like others who have posted comments, I won't pretend to understand the details of the specific question, but if the general question is how to use jq to emit newline-delimited JSON (that is, ensure that each JSON text is followed by a newline, and that no other (raw) newlines are added), the answer is simple: use jq with the `-c` option, and without the `-r` option.

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory examination of your data, the filter

```
.users[]
```

will give you just the user data to load and the filter

```
.scroll_param
```

will return just the scroll parameter.  If you put your data in a file you could invoke jq once for each filter but if you have to stream the data you could simply use the `,` operator to return one value after another.  e.g.

```
  .scroll_param
, .users[]
```

If you use that filter along with the `-c` option jq will generate output like

```
"24ba0fac-b8f9-46b2-944a-9bb523dcd1b1"
{"type":"user","id":"581c13632f25960e6e3dc89a","user_id":"ieo2e6dtsqhiyhtr",...
{"type":"user","id":"581c22a19a1dc02c460541df","user_id":"1o3helrdv58cxm7jf",...
```

presumably the script that reads the output from jq could capture the first line for use in the `curl` invocation and put the rest of the data into the file you load.

Hope this helps.